# React Typescript - how to typecheck a custom Checkbox component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-typescript

I'm currently working on a personal project to build a design system in React using Typescript. I'd like to take advantage of some of the types pre-defined within the React project for HTML elements, especially form controls such as  `ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>`. I'm currently working on a Checkbox component which hides the standard HTML input checkbox but uses its checked state to style some custom HTML within its label.

I'm using Styled Components to provide styles but have been struggling with how to structure my interface/interfaces to typecheck this component.

I have created a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dubinsky-8r18vx?file=/src/checkbox.tsx) to show the component code, but `Checkbox.tsx` looks like so:

```js
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef } from 'react';
import * as S from './checkbox.styles';

export interface CheckboxInputProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export interface CheckboxProps extends CheckboxInputProps {
  label: string;
}

export const Checkbox = ({ label, disabled, ...props }: CheckboxProps) => {
  return (
    <S.Checkbox>
      <S.CheckboxInput disabled={disabled} {...props} />
      <S.CheckboxLabel>
        <S.CheckboxBackground>
          <S.CheckboxIndicator>
            <S.CheckboxIcon />
          </S.CheckboxIndicator>
        </S.CheckboxBackground>
        <S.CheckboxText>{label}</S.CheckboxText>
      </S.CheckboxLabel>
    </S.Checkbox>
  );
};
```

I'd like some advice on how/if I can create a single interface for this component which also uses `ComponentPropsWithoutRef` or whether I need to create separate interfaces for each and every sub-component. Appreciate the question is a bit vague but I'd just like some guidance on how to structure this.